# substract specific string from data sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL
If I have a column like this

```
ID
00001234
00012345
00001235
00123456
```

I want to see a column of ID without '0' Like this

```
ID
1234
12345
1235
123456
```

How can I start? any advice?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: Is ID a character type column? (Odd choice...) `trim(leading '0' from ID)`

Comment: it's varchar(8) for the column

Comment: And the database is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use:

```
SELECT ID,
       REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ID, '0', ' ') ), ' ', '0')
FROM mytable
```

The above can be easily adjusted to any other RDBMS you may use.

Comment: If you have an ANSI SQL compliant dbms only TRIM is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to Bigint and cast it back to varchar

Note:Assumption: RDBMS SQL SERVER, ID is of character type

```
SELECT * INTO #TAB  FROM (
select '00001234' ID
UNION ALL
select '00012345'
UNION ALL
select '00001235'
UNION ALL
select '00123456'
)A


SELECT CAST(CAST(ID AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(50)) FROM #TAB
```